# Cannot connect oflaDemo stream from another computer in server

Tags: red5, red5-recorder

I have installed Red5 server in my mac and then take the oflaDemo war file and put it in webapps in Red5 folder and restarted.

Now I opened up Adobe Flash Media Encoder in another system and then put `rtmp://myip/oflaDemo` in FMS URL and then I click on "start" however its showing the below error which I have taken a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Questions about general software are kind of offtopic here.  Better try at superuser.stackexchange

Comment: @Trilarion is not red5 server specific software? I am trying to configure it so that I could stream from my laptop using RTMP!!!

Comment: And what has it to do with programming?

Comment: Check your server logs and ensure that oflaDemo is loaded; then check for connection attempts by FMLE.

Comment: Thanx for the support @PaulGregoire..I already resolved the issue. The issue was with Java incompatibility with Red5 1.0.5. I downgraded the version and now I am good.